# How should I fill na using the fillna result of the previous row?

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe...

```
money change
2     2
1     1 
na    2
na    2
na    1
1     1
```

I would like the na value be the previous value plus the change value from the previous row. Note that non-nan entries do not necessarily follow this pattern. 
How should I fill the na entries under column money so that it looks like the following...

```
money change
2     2
1     1 
2     2
4     2
6     1
1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by using simple concept of `python's dictionary`. Please check:

```
dfDict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
prevMoney = 0
prevChange = 0
outDictList = []
for aDict in dfDict:
    curMoney = aDict['money']
    curChange = aDict['change']
    if str(aDict['money'])=='nan':
        aDict['money'] = prevMoney + prevChange
    prevMoney = curMoney
    prevChange = curChange
    outDictList.append(aDict)

pd.DataFrame(outDictList)
```

output:

```
   change  money
0     2.0    2.0
1     1.0    1.0
2     2.0    2.0
3     2.0    4.0
4     1.0    6.0
5     1.0    1.0
```